# Python: Using a variable with a value defined in 1 function, being used in another function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, variables

```
def getValidSeason( ):
   season = input ( "Enter a season between 1980 and 2016: " )
   while season < 1980 or season > 2016:
      season = input ( "Enter a season between 1980 and 2016: " )
   return season

def getValidDriver( ):
  driver = input ( "Enter a driver's name: " )
  # This is where the first problem is
  # I want to be able to use the value of season from getValidSeason( )           
  # in the getValidDriver( ) function
  while getValidSeason( ) != 1980 and driver != "Steve Park" or driver != "Jamie McMurray"
     driver = input ( "Enter a driver's name: " )
  return driver

def printResults( ):
   # Basically the same as before, I want the value of the driver
   # variable defined in the getValidDriver( ) to be used in the print results( ) function    
   print ( "The driver being selected is",getValidDriver( ) )

def main( ):
   # I don't believe my question has anything to do with what you put in the main function , but I might be wrong.
```

I looked around and could not find help with my problem. I am sorry if there is already a solution out there, but I couldn't find anything. Maybe I was wrong. I'm struggling with programming. I did find a question on this website that was basically the same question but it involved an earlier version of Python, and they were talking about stuff that is no longer used in the current version of Python.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What precisely *is* the problem? Give a [mcve], not a vague description. Note that Python is case sensitive, and user `input`s are always strings.

Comment: Why is return capitalized?

Comment: return being capitalized was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very close (although I don't understand the condition of the `while` loop). I cleaned up the formatting such as lowercase R in `return` and spacing conventions in function calls. I changed the `input`s to convert to `ints` in `getValidSeason()` since you are trying to get strings. I also added some print lines in the `while` loop for my own benefit.

Also importantly, you don't need a `main` here (although it would be ok), but you do need to call your `printResults()` function to get the code running (the very last line of code). Let me know if you have questions about something I did or didn't explain.

CODE:

```
def getValidSeason():
   season = int(input("Enter a season between 1980 and 2016: "))
   while season < 1980 or season > 2016:
      season = int(input("Enter a season between 1980 and 2016: "))
   return season

def getValidDriver():
  driver = input("Enter a driver's name: ")
  season = getValidSeason()

  # This is where the first problem is
  # I want to be able to use the value of season from getValidSeason( )           
  # in the getValidDriver() function
  #EDIT: Not sure what logic you actually want here
  while season != 1980 and driver != "Steve Park" or driver != "Jamie McMurray":
      print('Last driver selected was: '+str(driver))
      print('Last season selected was: '+str(season))
      driver = input("Enter a driver's name: ")
      season = getValidSeason()

  return driver

def printResults():
   # Basically the same as before, I want the value of the driver
   # variable defined in the getValidDriver() to be used in the print results() function
   valid_driver = getValidDriver()
   print ("The driver being selected is",valid_driver)

printResults()
```

EDIT:

```
#This is Function "func1"
#It takes the variable "name" as its one and only argument
#   and it adds '_1' to the end of it before returning name
def func1(name):
    print('In func1 you passed in the name: '+name)

    print('Adding "_1" to the end of the name')
    name = name+'_1'
    print('In func1 your new name is: '+name)
    print('')

    return name

#Just like func1
def func2(name):
    print('In func2 you passed in the name: '+name)

    print('Adding "_2" to the end of the name')
    name = name+'_2'
    print('In func2 your new name is: '+name)
    print('')

    return name

#Function that will ask the user for a name
#Doesn't take any arguments
#Returns the name
def get_name():
    name = 'Steve' #<-- just set to always be steve for now (you can replace this w/ an 'input()')

    print('Your original name was '+name)
    print('')

    name_f1 = func1(name) #<-- original name w/ '_1' added to the back
    name_f2 = func2(name) #<-- original name w/ '_2' added to the back

    name_f1_f2 = func2(name_f1) #<-- orig name w' '_1_2' added to the back
    name_f2_f1 = func1(name_f2) #<-- orig name w' '_2_1' added to the back

    return name


#Call the get_name function which will then call func1 and func2
get_name()
```

Comment: When I type the code you provided I get an error. First, it asks me to type a driver's name. I type in Steve Park. Then I get this message: Trackback (most recent call last): File "Stdin>", line1 in <module> File"Stdin>", line2, in printResults File "Stdin>", line2, in getValidDriver File "<string>, line1 Steve Park

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that error. I'm using python 3.5.2. The error you've commented is cutoff and doesn't have the actual error bit, could you include that? As for your second comment you would need to pass the value of `getValidSeason()` as an argument to your functions. Look for help online for "python function arguments"

Comment: I have another question that I didn't want to make a separate topic about. What do I do if I want to get the value of season from getValidSeason( ) in many separate functions? I wouldn't want to call getValidSeason( ) many times because it would run the function many, and ask me for the season many times.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. My laptop computer keyboard isn't working so I'm using an Android app Python IDE. That might be why I am getting the weird error. When you say to pass the value of getValidSeason() as an argument to your functions, do you mean to put getValidSeasons inside of the parentheses next to the function name of the functions that will use it?

Comment: I've added an EDIT section to my answer to clarify what I meant in my comment. Try running it and working through what is happening!

Comment: I believe I understood the code you just put up. I'm getting my new keyboard in a couple days so I can't type the code yet, but I think I understand what is going on there. I don't think it answered my question though, unless I am missing something. Let's say in get_name( ) it asks the user to type in a name, and the user types in Tom. The variable that stores this is called name1. Now I want to use the variable name1 in multiple different functions, but I want the value of name1 to automatically be = to the user input defined in get_name( ) without the user having to type it again.

Comment: I think I could ask the user the question by using a global variable to ask it, but isn't it proper coding to have it inside a function? Functions are supposed to do 1 thing each and be used to break the program up. Putting the question outside of a function I think you aren't supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to save the functions' return value in a variable in the other function. Here's an example for `printResults`:

```
def printResults():
  driver = getValidDriver()
  # you can now use the 'driver' variable
  print("The driver being selected is", driver)
```

Answer (score -1):

[Python Course](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php) Shows that you simply need to add the `global` flag if you want to declare the variable as global inside a function. to further quote [Python Course](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php) :

*"The way Python uses global and local variables is maverick. While in many or most other programming languages variables are treated as global if not otherwise declared, Python deals with variables the other way around. They are local, if not otherwise declared."*

I am not sure if this will resolve your issue completely since you are returning the variable back out. Thats simply the first thing I noticed about your code.

Comment: This does not need to use `global`, it's just getting return values from functions.

Answer (score -1):

"I believe I understood the code you just put up. I'm getting my new keyboard in a couple days so I can't type the code yet, but I think I understand what is going on there. I don't think it answered my question though, unless I am missing something. Let's say in get_name( ) it asks the user to type in a name, and the user types in Tom. The variable that stores this is called name1. Now I want to use the variable name1 in multiple different functions, but I want the value of name1 to automatically be = to the user input defined in get_name( ) without the user having to type it again.

I think I could ask the user the question by using a global variable to ask it, but isn't it proper coding to have it inside a function? Functions are supposed to do 1 thing each and be used to break the program up. Putting the question outside of a function I think you aren't supposed to do. "

I read your comments on the comment section. I posted them above. I think the only thin you can do is call the function or created a global variable.